# @PreAuthorize doesn't work with function which is called from another function

Tags: java, spring-security

I am trying to understand spring security. I am using java-config instead of xml. I tried creating a controller and then tested `@PreAuthorize` notation. But in my given code this `@PreAuthorize` only works if I use it with the `getActiveSessions` function but it has no effect when I use it with `getName` function. So this code works as expected

```
public class DemoSessionController extends SessionController{

        @RequestMapping("/welcome/{a}")
        @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
        public String getActiveSessions(@PathVariable String a) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String str = getName(a);
            return str;
        }

        public String getName(String name) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return "This is "+name+"";
        }
    }
```

But this doesn't

```
public class DemoSessionController extends SessionController{

    @RequestMapping("/welcome/{a}")
    public String getActiveSessions(@PathVariable String a) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String str = getName(a);
        return str;
    }

    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
    public String getName(String name) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return "This is "+name+"";
    }
}
```

Can someone explain why the second case doesn't work and how can I make it work? Thanks !!

Comment: Spring uses proxies to apply AOP. When using proxies only method calls INTO the object pass through the proxy, internal method calls bypass the proxy. TO make it work you will need a full blown AOP solution, like AspectJ with either load or compile timeweaving.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thanks for the prompt and clear reply. I get why this doesn't work now. About making it work, the way you say 'full blown', does it mean that the solution would be cumbersome? Can you please give links to any resource that might help? Thanks !!

Comment: I got it to work with Java config but I don't have access to my code right now. Basically, there are two contexts (DispatcherServlet vs some other). The annotations will only work if the security is configuration applies to the correct (or both) contexts. Search the net and you'll find the solution. It will work once the configuration is correct.

Comment: Please add your Java Spring config to the question. That's the part that'll need to be fixed.

Comment: @Codo Thanks for the reply, I understand what you want to say but that isn't the issue I am facing. In fact I am not using any DispatcherServlet. I can get the annotation to work but it only happens when I use it with the first method. After posting this question I learnt that the issue occurs because the methods are part of the same bean. However I am not able to resolve it !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, annotations are only processed when the object is called from outside. There are a couple of solutions.

You could split the methods that need annotations to be processed in a separate object, e.g. an AdminObject which is annotated with

```
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
```

on the class level. That way you don't need to annotate each method. You should mark internal methods in the class private to prevent them being used from outside. This requires to reorder the application logic, but it might helpful to have all the admin tasks in one object.

Another solution is obviously to add the required annotations for all tasks the a method does, including the ones executed by methods used by the public methods.

**EDIT 1:**

Added sample classes to make the proposed solution clearer

```
public class UserSessionController extends SessionController{
@Inject
private AdminFacade adminFacade;

@RequestMapping("/welcome/{a}")
public String getActiveSessions(@PathVariable String a) {
    return adminFacade.getName(a);
}
}

@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
public class AdminFacade {

public String getName(String name) {
    return "This is "+name;
}
public String getDetailsForAdmin(String param) {
    return "admin details";
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply !! However I can't understand you. Can you please add some code to explain the first approach? Is this approach equivalent to saying that I need to have the getName() method in some other bean? Thanks !!

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot for the edit. Your suggestion does work. I did try a similar approach and it didn't work earlier. Reason was that I was doing something similar to this, return new AdminFacade().getName(a) but this didn't work. In your case, you are injecting AdminFacade object which has not been initialized. I have two doubts in fact. 1.) Why does your approach work and mine not. 2) Why doesn't adminFacade.getName(a) produce a null pointer because I can't see how it is being initialized ? Please clear my doubt and I will accept your answer !! Thanks !!

Comment: The cdi container (spring in your case) will create an AdminFacade object and set it to the variable, when it sees the @Inject. Creating the object manually won't work, as the cdi container then cannot do it's "magic", i.e. processing other annotations, when methods on the object are called. I suggest you have a look at the CDI tutorial http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/giwhl.html if you want to know more details.